# Adding rails relation by id rather than finding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

At the moment, I have some code to generate a pack of trading cards for a game that looks something like this;

```
class Pack < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :release
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cards

  after_create :fill_pack

  private

  # Randomly generate pack contents
  def fill_pack
    ids = self.release.cards.pluck(:id)
    (15).times do |i|
      self.cards << Card.find(ids[rand(ids.length)])
    end
  end
end
```

The particular part that concerns me is `self.cards << Card.find(ids[rand(ids.length)])`. That is making 15 SELECT queries! That's probably a bad idea. ;)

I already have a list of ids grabbed before with pluck. There must be some way I can just use those, right? I had tried `self.cards.create :card_id => ids[rand(ids.length)]` but self.cards.create is for creating a new card, not a new reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use an `in` (untested but close):

```
self.cards = Card.where('id in (?)', ids.sample(15))
```

Or set the IDs directly:

```
self.card_ids = ids.sample(15)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without looking up the model by using the `card_ids` parameter that gets added to your `Pack` class by `has_and_belongs_to_many`, like so:

```
self.card_ids << ids[rand(ids.length)]
```

After you set `card_ids`, `self.cards` will be all the cards that map to those IDs.

Comment: Do I need to refresh the relation or something after doing that? It seems to think it's empty.

Comment: It looks like you need to actually set the IDs instead of appending them - after running some quick tests, `self.card_ids = [1,2,3]` will work.